# ImportError with Numpy using Python/C 3.12 API subinterpreters

Tags: numpy, cpython, python-subinterpreters

I'm attempting to run a python script that spawns a subinterpreter and a main interpreter, each responsible for doing some sort of work ([Based on the example used in this article](https://martinheinz.dev/blog/97)). The work I'm having both interpreters do involves use of the NumPy library, and when I go to run my code, I get the following error:

```
_xxsubinterpreters.RunFailedError: <class 'ImportError'>: Error importing numpy: 
       you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit 
       the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there.
```

I initially suspected that this had to do with my NumPy install, but found this in the [Real Python writeup on Python 3.12 Subinterpreters](https://realpython.com/python312-subinterpreters/):

> With the GIL moving to be a per-interpreter state, this guaranteed thread safety is removed. To prevent either a large number of bugs in existing extension modules or a lack of adoption of Python 3.12, methods were added so that when you want to import a module, Python can first determine whether it’s ready for this new feature.

And:

> Note: If a subinterpreter with a per-interpreter GIL attempts to import a module that doesn’t support this feature, then Python will raise an ImportError.

Is it just the case that the Interpreters module in the Python/C API 3.12 Interpreters module does not yet support NumPy? Otherwise, I'm not sure what the issue might be.